# HTM/CSS interfering with D3.js

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I have put together a d3 visualisation on codepen where it runs as planned:

https://codepen.io/MrVincentRyan/pen/oJLNrV?editors=1010

However when I add additional styling with HTML and CSS the line element no longer appears:

https://codepen.io/MrVincentRyan/pen/VqKLbm?editors=1010

HTML:

```html
<head>
  </head
<body>
  <div class="intro">
      <div class="flexwrap">
        <div class="headline">
          <div class="topline">
            <!-- <time class="date">01.03.2018</time> -->
          <h1 class="title">The sound of the pound</h1>
          <h3 class="introtext">From flash crashes, to snap elections, the pound has been rattling around currency markets as Brexit threatens to play a new tune with the UK's economy.</h3>
        </div>

  <div id="audioviz">
   <button id="buttons" onclick="playAudio()" id="start">Start</button>
 <button id="buttons" onclick="audio.stop()" id="reset">Reset</button>
    </div>
  <audio id="myAudio">
  <source src="https://res.cloudinary.com/dxeddkkwh/video/upload/v1544798173/1544797413_5gbSBNViC81pMgpVitW7.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
Your browser does not support the audio element.
</audio>
  </div>
        </div>
      </div>

    </div>

    <div class="annotation-list layout-small" id="surveychart-annotations">
      <div class="flexwrap">
        <div class="annotation-list__item">
          <div class="annotation-list__number">1</div>
          <div class="annotation-list__text">
          <h3>Brexit referendum June 23 2016</h3>
  <div class="annotation-list__img-box"><img class="annotation-list__img" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2018/07/31/16/06/brexit-3575384_1280.jpg"/></div>
          <p>Following the vote for Brexit on June 23 the pound plunged <strong>from $1.43</strong> the week before the Brexit vote <strong>to $1.36</strong> as the market panicked following the result. <strong>David Cameron</strong> the Prime Minister resigned and Theresa May emerged as an unlikely leader to see Brexit through.</p>
```

Comment: What is CSSL? Also, please include all relevant code here on Stack Overflow, not on an external site.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please read https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve and then edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Apologies, but if i include all the code there is too much. I'm not sure what is triggering the issue that is why I am struggling to cut it down

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you see an issue with this line of HTML code?

`<button id="buttons" onclick="playAudio()" id="start">Start</button>`

Multiple IDs? Change it to either a class or a data-attribute or anything else other than a second ID and it'll work.

A fork: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/yGameg

Comment: Thanks couldn't see the wood from the trees.

Comment: Haha. No sweat!